# Writing a single query for mutliple where condition using same column same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, conditional-statements

In my table one of  filed is msg. Based this filed two  where condition. The condition are

```
where  msg  like '%fatal%' or msg like '%exception%' or msg like '%fopen%'

then Select telco ,
Sum(Case when a= '1' then 1 else 0 end) as a, 
Sum(Case when b= '2' then 1 else 0 end) as b, 
Sum(Case when c= '3' then 1 else 0 end) as c,


where  msg not like '%fatal%' or msg not like '%exception%' or msg not like   '%fopen%'
then Select telco ,
Sum(Case when a= '1' then 1 else 0 end) as a_e, 
Sum(Case when b= '2' then 1 else 0 end) as b_e, 
Sum(Case when c= '3' then 1 else 0 end) as c_e,

From temp_inbox  group by t
```

here a, b ,c column name

I want to write the above requirement one query. If i write two query based two where condition then i get result but i want to write single query and show my result in the following way :

```
a   b   c   a_e   b_e   c_e

5   6   7    10    4     10
1   2   7     45   20    2
```

sample data:

```
         a  b   c  msg

         1  0   0  fatalerror

         0  0   3   successed
         1  0   0   exception
         0  2   0   successful
```

Comment: can you please post what are the two queries? The query example that you have given is out of any sql standard. I really can not understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: please read sql sum and case tutorial then you will understand what have  i said

Comment: can you please post a link to the tutorial...
and isn't this the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857954/writing-a-single-query-for-mutliple-queries-with-same-where-condition-same-table the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select telco, 
sum(
     case when (msg  like '%fatal%' or out_msg like '%exception%' or out_msg like '%fopen%') and a = '1' 
     then 1 else 0 end 
) as a,
sum(
     case when (msg  like '%fatal%' or out_msg like '%exception%' or out_msg like '%fopen%') and a = '2' 
     then 1 else 0 end 
) as b,
sum(
     case when (msg  like '%fatal%' or out_msg like '%exception%' or out_msg like '%fopen%') and a = '3' 
     then 1 else 0 end 
) as c,
 sum(
     case when (msg not like '%fatal%' or out_msg not like '%exception%' or out_msg not like '%fopen%') and a = '1' 
     then 1 else 0 end 
) as a_e,
sum(
     case when (msg not like '%fatal%' or out_msg not like '%exception%' or out_msg not like '%fopen%') and a = '2' 
     then 1 else 0 end 
) as b_e,
sum(
     case when (msg not like '%fatal%' or out_msg not like '%exception%' or out_msg not like '%fopen%') and a = '3' 
     then 1 else 0 end 
) as c_e

From temp_inbox  group by t
```

or you can use nested case when insted

Comment: no sir, i want to sum a , b , c column based msg column condition

Comment: @salma could you please post the sample data in your table that you run this query against becouse i can't understand your query.

Comment: @salma what's wrong with my query it is sum a,b,c based on the msg condition

Comment: sorry sir,firstly i did not understand you query. at last i understood it. it works . thanks a lot. i know i did not express my question properly.But your co-operation help me to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UNION statement to join two queries with same number of columns:

I am not sure what are you trying to do, but a UNION statement from the table you mentioned would look something like this:

```
select sum(a), message from telco where message like '%fatal%'
UNION
select sum(a), message from telco where message not like '%fatal%'
```

Comment: i want individual  result in two column , one for message like '%fatal%' and another for message not like '%fatal%'. but you query give one result for sum "message like '%fatal%' and message not like '%fatal%"'